# Geolocation - Ionic 3 weather app works correctly if I start with GPS enabled

Tags: ionic3

My Ionic 3 weather app works correctly if I start with GPS enabled.

If I start the app with the GPS turned off, and having subscribed to listen to changes (see below watch.subscribe), although then manually enable it it does not recover latitude and longitude. I would like help please to control the GPS, that is, to "listen" to the on and off event, to be able to operate on that. Thank you!

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
this.global.latitude = resp.coords.latitude
this.global.longitude = resp.coords.longitude
  }).catch((error) => {
alert('Error getting location ' + error);
  });
  let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
  watch.subscribe((data) => {
   this.global.latitude = data.coords.latitude
   this.global.longitude = data.coords.longitude
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It also happens that the behavior of the phone varies depending on the accuracy you have (example: in iOS, it's necessary to **"true"** in **enableHighAccuracy**).

I also had many issues with the location capability and ended up solving it as next:

create **api.provider** and inject into component:

**-geo options declaration:**

```js
private geoOptions: GeolocationOptions = {
     enableHighAccuracy: true,
     timeout: 6000,
     maximumAge: 12000
};
```

**-onInit called from constructor:**

```js
public onInit(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve: (value?: boolean | any) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => {
       this.getCurrentPosition().subscribe((response: any) => {
           resolve(response);
       }, (err: any) => {
           reject(err);
       });
   });
}
```

-constructor that already handles **getCurrentPosition** errors and varies the accuracy options to call back before executing **watchPosition**:

```js
constructor(public api: Api, private gps: Geolocation, private toast: ToastController) {
        const locationSubscription = this.isLocationActive.subscribe((response: any) => {
            const initExecute = () => {
                this.onInit()
                .then((val: any) => {
                    this.watchPosition().subscribe();
                    locationSubscription.unsubscribe();
                }).catch((reason: any) => {
                    // if fails, turn enableHighAccuracy options (some Android devices do not have HighAccuracy available)
                    this.geoOptions.enableHighAccuracy = !this.geoOptions.enableHighAccuracy;
                    initExecute();
                });
            };

            if (response && (response as boolean).toString().toLowerCase() === "true") {
                initExecute();
            }
        });
    }
```

-the **currentPosition** wrapped method:

```js
 public getCurrentPosition(): Observable<Geoposition> {
        // Create an Observable that will start listening to geolocation updates
        // when a consumer subscribes
        return Observable.create((observer: Observer<Geoposition>) => {
            this.gps.getCurrentPosition(this.geoOptions).then((response: any) => {            // your todo validator
                // this.validateGeolocationResponse(err, observer, true);
            }).catch((err: any) => {
                // your todo validator
                // this.validateGeolocationResponse(err, observer, true);
            });
            // When the consumer unsubscribes, clean up data ready for next subscription.
            // return { unsubscribe() { navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId); }};
        });
    }
```

-and finally, the **watchPosition** method:

```js
public watchPosition(): Observable<Geoposition> {
        return Observable.create((observer: Observer<Geoposition>) => {
            this.gps.watchPosition(this.geoOptions).subscribe((response: any) => {
                // your validation method if coords are returned
                this.validateGeolocationResponse(response, observer);
            }, (err: any) => {
                // your validation method if coords are returned
                this.validateGeolocationResponse(err, observer, true);
            });
        });
    }
```

**-Tip**
Create a **ReplaySubject** to store the last right coord values. It doesn't always return successfully, therefore it is advisable to search for the latest successes and return them to your subscriber if the current ones fail.

E.g.:

```js
public currentLocation = new ReplaySubject<Geoposition>(2);
```

**Blessings for you too!**

Comment: Thank you ! Although the code appears difficult for my Ionic 3 level, I get to work

Blessings to you

Comment: Yes, I can understand you. But read it bit by bit. Intention commented each section for major understanding. Any questions, you can write me again. ;) (and rate the answer if it is useful: P). -Sincerely